# Change the default path of ASP.net website

Tags: asp.net

When debugging my current solution, it always output to mylocalhost:port/default.aspx. How to I force it to output to another path like mylocalhost:port/Default/default.aspx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on your project select properties (or press F4) and you can change port number, and virtual path like  `\default`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it in your web application's settings (right click project and choose `Settings` from menu or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>), like this:

[image]